# React: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, reactjs

I am taking my first steps with React and got stuck on this error:

> "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined     at Region.render (Region.js:52)"

The file in question looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

import {
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';


class Region extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            region: [],
            error: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.area_id;
    this.fetchData(id);
  }

  fetchData(id) {
      fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/area_id/'+id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('data', data);
            this.setState({
                region: data.objects,
            });
        })
          .catch((err) => {
             console.log('villa', err)
              this.setState({
                  error: true,
              })
          });
  }
  render() {
    const { region, error } = this.state;

    console.log(region);
    const list = region.map((region) => { //THIS IS LINE 52
        const link = '/region/' + region.id + '/farm/' +region.farm_id;

        return (
            <li key={region.farm_id}><Link to={link}>Area:     
{region.area_name} - <bold>Farm:</bold>{region.farm_name} </Link></li>
      );
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Region</h2>
        <br/>
          {error ? (<p>Error getting data!</p>) : null}
        <ul className="link-list">
          {list}
        </ul>
        <Link to="/">Back</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Region;
```

And the API at "http://localhost:5000/api/area_id" looks like this:

```
{
  "num_results": 7, 
  "objects": [
    {
      "area_id": 1, 
      "area_name": "\u00c1shreppur", 
      "farms": [
        {
          "area_id": 1, 
          "area_name": "\u00c1shreppur", 
          "farm_id": 1, 
          "farm_name": "HVAMMUR"
        }, 
        {
          "area_id": 1, 
          "area_name": "\u00c1shreppur", 
          "farm_id": 2, 
          "farm_name": "HVAMMKOT"
        }, 
.....
```

To add some more details, I can tell you that this is the first edition of a history of a certain area and who lived where and when. So there are 7 areas, each area has farms on it, and each farm has a recored of names and years about who used to live at some point.

So the first page loads. I get up a list of 7 area links. When pressing one of the links I get this error. After I get through this, I want to be able to click any one of the farms to get the list of habitants on that farm and the years they lived there.

Comment: Considering that your error is at the "render" call, it would help having the render function code here as well.

Comment: It's there, just scroll down the code part.

Comment: What is the route that you render on `'/region/' + region.id + '/farm/' +region.farm_id;`

Comment: since you have a promise you can add a check at the beginning of your render function `render() { if(this.state.region.length) { ...}`

Comment: Can you show console output, please?

Comment: try `(region || []).map((region) => { /* ... */ })`

Comment: Yes, by checking full console output I found one error in assigning value to "id" variable when I fetchData. Here it is:
[]
Region.js:30 GET http://localhost:5000/api/area_id/undefined 404 (NOT FOUND)
fetchData @ Region.js:30
componentDidMount @ Region.js:26
.....
Region.js:33 data Object {}
Region.js:52 undefined
Region.js:40 villa TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Region.render (Region.js:53)
...
Region.js:52 undefined
Region.js:53 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Region.render (Region.js:53)

Comment: But, when hardcoding id variable it still errors. 
[]length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
Region.js:33 data Object {area_id: 1, area_name: "Áshreppur", farms: Array(34)}
Region.js:52 undefined
Region.js:40 villa TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Region.render (Region.js:53)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:796

Region.js:52 undefined
Region.js:53 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Region.render (Region.js:53)

Comment: Sorry, that is really hard to read.

Comment: I guess there is a problem with context. Try to change signature of `fetchData` method to `fetchData = id => {...}`

Comment: Thank you Hitmands, that works. :) The 'id' variable is still not delivering any values, but the undefined error is gone.

Comment: I think this is the trouble line: `const id = this.props.match.params.area_id;` Why? The parameter is called area_id, why can I not access it like that?

Comment: Ok, when changing the fetchData to: `fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/area_id/1') //+id)`it still doesn't render though. The console output says: 
`data Object {num_results: 7, objects: Array(7), page: 1, total_pages: 1}
 [] Region.js:35 (fetchData line) 
data Object {area_id: 1, area_name: "Áshreppur", farms: Array(34)}
 undefined`
So something more is probably wrong, since it doesn't render even without the "id" variable.

Comment: I really suck at making readable comments. Sorry guys!

Comment: So, wrapping it up. This is the problem: _GET http://localhost:5000/api/area_id/undefined 404 (NOT FOUND)_

So what is wrong with this: `const id = this.props.match.params.area_id;` in `componentDidMount()` ? Is there another way to do that?

Comment: One step closer, now it gets the correct data. Just doesn't render it yet. data `Object {area_id: 6, area_name: "Engihlíðarhreppur", farms: Array(43)}, **undefined**`

Comment: @Ingibjorg It might be easier to format things nicely if you update your question rather than making comments